# Backbone Js - parse data issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I'm trying to parse data to a collection view from a json file that has number key for each group of data within it. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "0": {
        "artifact_id": "36",
        "timestamp": "2013-08-20 11:59:00",
        "modified": "2013-08-20 11:59:00",
        "text": "Why did the last one duplicate? I don't think I clicked it twice...",
        "author_desc": "",
        "object_type": "artifact",
        "comments": []
    },
    "1": {
        "artifact_id": "35",
        "timestamp": "2013-08-20 11:57:51",
        "modified": "2013-08-20 11:57:51",
        "text": "This is a new artifact for a new day.",
        "author_desc": "",
        "object_type": "artifact",
        "comments": []
    },
    "2": {
        "artifact_id": "34",
        "timestamp": "2013-08-20 11:57:50",
        "modified": "2013-08-20 11:57:50",
        "text": "This is a new artifact for a new day.",
        "author_desc": "",
        "object_type": "artifact",
        "comments": []
    }
}
```

How do I write a model parse to take each one of the entries (0, 1, 2... etc) as each model from within the data?

This is my collection, with the suggested addition from Casey below, however it doesn't seem to be running the parse method:

```
var FriendCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: FriendModel,
    parse: function(data) {
        console.log('running parse');
        return _.map(data, _.identity);
    }
});
var friendCollection = new FriendCollection();
friendCollection.reset(friendjson);
```

Comment: collection.parse is only ran when a fetch is made from a server. http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Collection#reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) does not call [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) and there's no way to make it call `parse`. You have a few options:

1. Convert `friendjson` to an array by hand and give `reset` that array.
2. Don't `reset` at all, just hand `friendjson` to the collection's constructor and include the [`{parse: true}` option](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-constructor).
3. Replace your collection's `reset` with your own version that does call `parse` if you include a `{parse: true}` option.

**1** should be pretty obvious.

**2** would look like this:

```
var friendCollection = new FriendCollection(friendjson, { parse: true });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dbM82/

**3** would look something like this:

```
var FriendCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //...
    reset: function(models, options) {
        if(options && options.parse) {
            delete options.parse;
            models = this.parse(models);
        }
        return Backbone.Collection.prototype.reset.call(this, models, options);
    }
});

var friendCollection = new FriendCollection();
friendCollection.reset(friendjson, { parse: true });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Rs8es/

Comment: Thanks @mu is too short, that did it. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Or, if this is a special circumstance you could call the parse function directly: `friendCollection.reset(friendCollection.parse(friendjson))`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Collection#parse` method.

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  parse: function (data) {
    return _.map(data, _.identity);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Casey Foster, doesn't seem to be working though. The parse method doesn't seem to be getting called. I've added the collection code to the original post above.

Comment: I assumed you were calling `fetch` to get this data. Since you're using `reset`, you'll want to pass the `parse: true` option. `friendCollection.reset(friendjson, {parse: true});`

Comment: I would like to be able to use the fetch option, but I can't seem to get it running either... I'm trying to work up to it by using the data this way first.

Either way, running friendCollection.length is still only returning 1 unfortunately.

Comment: The `parse: true` option is implied when you use `fetch`, but you have to explicitly set it when you're using other methods like `set` or `reset`.